# How to analyze why "Try Ubuntu" does not launch?

Tags: 12.10, boot, live-usb, 32-bit, desktop-environments

I downloaded the [latest version of Ubuntu Desktop for i386](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) since I like to run it on an older computer which does not support 64bit. I successfully following this [tutorial on how to create a bootable USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick). The computer boots the stick as expected and stops to let me choose between *Try Ubuntu* and *Install Ubuntu* as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Ubuntu bootable USB stick options screen]

I have chosen the *Try Ubuntu* option. The option dialog disappears as the menu bar does. I waited for more then two hours but **all I see is the background image** and the **mouse cursor** which can be moved. When I press the power switch on the computer a menu pops up which offers me options to either shutdown or restart the computer.

How can I analyze the boot process in order to find out why the *Try Ubuntu* feature does not work?

Comment: First, you should try downloading another ISO and with another USB stick, also you can verify the [checksum of the ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Comment: And second, if that doesn't work, this question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic. Take a look at the [instructions on filing a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Thanks!

Comment: I verified the MD5 hash of the ISO. It matches with the given value on the [UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) website.